# Sunspot_rails returns no results for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot-rails

I have an application with a relationship such that a User has_many Tags. I am trying to set up the sunspot_rails gem to be able to search the user's name (working fine) as well as their associated tags.

My controller code is the following:

```
searchable do
  text :first_name, :last_name
  text :user_tags do
    tags.map(&:title)
  end
end
```

I have a single user with the tag "programming", however a search for programming returns no results. The solr query I see on the server is:

```
SOLR Request (4.7ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:User"], q: "programming", fl: "* score", qf: "first_name_text last_name_text user_tags_text", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
```

I don't really know much about solr and haven't been able to find good, concise explanations of how to go about reading that query, so I haven't been able to track down the problem. Any ideas or good resources I can check out?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The only problem was that I forgot to reindex solr using rake sunspot:solr:reindex after adding the tag to the user.